# How to return the contents of another plpgsql function?

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I have a plpgsql function `func` which returns a `setof integer`. I now have another function `func2` which should call and return `func`. Should I use `return next func()` or `return query select func()` here? Is there a difference in execution and performance? Or should I do something else?

```
create function func2() returns setof integer as $$
begin
    if true then -- logic omitted here
        return next func();
        -- return query select func();
    end if;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

I know I could store the outcome of `func()` into a local declared variable, but I don't think that is needed here. Correct me if I am wrong.

I read through the documentation, and could only find `return next` and `return query select` as alternatives for returning a local declared variable. But it's not clear to me if there is a difference between the two in this case, if any.

Sidenote, `return func()` does not seem to be possible, which is surprising coming from a background in regular procedural languages (C++ and Java mostly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RETURN NEXT func()` wouldn't work, because that can only return a single value. To do that, you'd have to loop through the results of `func()` and return each result with `RETURN NEXT`, which is unnecessarily complicated.

It is much easier to use

```
RETURN QUERY SELECT func();
```

Which returns all result values of `func()` in a single statement.

PL/pgSQL is quite differect in syntax from C++. It copies Oracle's PL/SQL, which in turn is derived from ADA.

Comment: That's surprising, because `return next func()` seems to work just fine? If it matters, I am hacking on PostgreSQL v11 latest beta.

Comment: Then you got lucky, and `func()` happens to return just a single row. Try with a `func()` that returns several rows.

Comment: You are right! I did not think about the case where I was returning multiple rows.